# Return a different type if array is empty in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to return a different type in the strict mode if the argument is an empty array:

```js
public static fromArray<T extends number[] | ({ length: 0 } & never[])>(
  array: T,
): T extends { length: 0 } ? undefined : ListNode {
  if (array.length === 0) {
    return undefined; // Error: TS2322: Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'T extends { length: 0; } ? undefined : ListNode'.
  }

  const start = new ListNode(array[0]);

  ...

  return start; // Error: TS2322: Type 'ListNode' is not assignable to type 'T extends { length: 0; } ? undefined : ListNode'.
}
```

The expected behavior:

```
const a = ListNode.fromArray([]); // typeof a is undefined
const b = ListNode.fromArray([1]); // typeof b is ListNode
```

If I add some type casting, e.g.

```js
  return start as T extends { length: 0 } ? undefined : ListNode;
```

then all works as expected. Is it possible to implement this without "hacks"?

Comment: Use the [null object design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern). It simplifies the code that uses this function (and it also solves your problem with the declarations.)

Comment: @axiac especially with data structures, I don't really find it useful to return some sort of "not here value" (null/undefined in JS) as opposed to empty data structure. Then consumers don't need to split their logic between "process nothing" and "process something" the latter of which is already a no-op for empty.

Comment: @axiac, thank you for a clue! But I don't want to change the implementation in my particular case. I also would throw an error if the argument is an empty array to have a more strict and maintainable implementation (which also simplifies types). But I'd like to solve this puzzle with types. 

Comment: The return type should be `ListNode | undefined`

Comment: You should overload your method. TS does not support condition types as a return type. See [example](https://tsplay.dev/mMxxlN)

Comment: `length` is known only at runtime. You can't return "either one type" at compile time. If the function can possibly return two different types, then its return type must be a union type of that two type.

Comment: @RickMo, I don't think so. I need a conditional return type so that TS returns a different type depending on the input, e.g.: `const a = new ListNode([]); // undefined` and `const b = new ListNode([1]); // ListNode`. If the return type is `ListNode | undefined` then you will get: `const a = new ListNode([]); // ListNode | undefined` and `const b = new ListNode([1]); // ListNode | undefined`.

Comment: @captain-yossarian, I'm not sure how this can be solved with overloads as eventually, I would get a similar error.

Comment: @RickyMo, I think, that TS should analyze the code as it has [Control flow based type analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#control-flow-based-type-analysis) and as I check `array.length === 0` it should work out. Am I missing something?

Comment: @KarpovKirill `array.length === 0` does not act as a typeguard for empty array

Comment: @captain-yossarian, that's why I have `({ length: 0 } & never[])` and `T extends { length: 0 } ? undefined...`. So, I thought it should have worked because I have a separate "rule" for `length: 0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this example:

```js
class ListNode<T> {
    constructor(arg: T) { }
}

type IsLiteralNumber<N extends number> =
    (N extends number
        ? (number extends N
            ? false
            : true)
        : true)
{
    // false
    type Test1 = IsLiteralNumber<number>

    // false, because TS is unaware how long is any[] array
    type Test2 = IsLiteralNumber<any[]['length']>

    // true, it is clear that provided array has 3 elements
    type Test3 = IsLiteralNumber<[1, 2, 3]['length']>

    // true, 5 is a literal type
    type Test4 = IsLiteralNumber<5>
}

/**
 * Whole trick here is to check whether T[length]
 * property has literal number type (1,2,3,4) or no (number)
 */
type IsTuple<T> =
    /**
     * Check whether T is an array
     */
    (T extends Array<any> ?
        /**
         * Check whether T[length] has literal number type
         */
        IsLiteralNumber<T['length']>
        /**
         * If T is not array it is obvious that it should be false
         */
        : false)

{
    /**
     * false, because is it ibvious that type number[] does 
     * not have fixed length
     */
    type Test1 = IsTuple<number[]>

    // true, fixed length is 0
    type Test2 = IsTuple<[]>

    // true, fixed length is 3
    type Test3 = IsTuple<[1, 1, 1]>

}

/**
 * If argument is Tuple infer literal type from 
 * first element, otherwise return a union of all types of array elements 
 */
type ListNodeHead<Tuple extends any[]> =
    /**
     * Check whether TUple is actually tuple
     */
    IsTuple<Tuple> extends true
    /**
     * If yes - infer exact type of first element
     */
    ? Tuple extends [infer H, ...infer _]
    ? ListNode<H>
    : never
    /**
     * Otherwise return a union of all elements type
     * Added undefined because array might be empty and this
     * length might be known only in runtime
     */
    : ListNode<Tuple[number]> | undefined


class Foo {
    public static fromArray(array: []): undefined
    public static fromArray<Elem extends number, Tuple extends Elem[]>(array: [...Tuple]): ListNodeHead<Tuple>
    public static fromArray<Tuple extends number[]>(
        array: Tuple
    ): undefined | ListNode<number> {
        return array.length === 0 ? undefined : new ListNode(array[0])

    }
}


const result = Foo.fromArray([]) // undefined
const result2 = Foo.fromArray([1]) // ListNode<1>

const foo = (arg: number[]) => Foo.fromArray(arg) // ListNode<number> | undefined
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NlggGw)

It works for literal types and more general types (works inside higher order function `foo`)

`IsTuple` check whether array has fixed length or not.

`Head` - returns first element if list is a tuple or just a type of elements in the list if it is not a tuple.

TS does not support conditional types as a return type, this is why I have overloaded `fromArray` method.

---

**Q & A**

> 1. Could you elaborate on that part `N extends number? (number extends N in particular number extends N` ?

`N extends number` - means that `N` is a subtype of `number` type. `N` has all props from `number` and may have some other extra props.
See example:

```js
type IsSubType<N> = N extends number ? true : false

type Test1 = IsSubType<number & { _tag: 'A' }> // true
type Test2 = IsSubType<5> // true
type Test3 = IsSubType<typeof Infinity> // true
```

All these types `number & { _tag: 'A' }, 5, typeof Infinity` are subtypes of `number`.

As for the second part: `number extends N`. See this example:

```js
/**
 * This conditional type is important only in context of my answer,
 */
type IsSuperType<N> = number extends N ? false : true

type Test1 = IsSuperType<10> // true
type Test2 = IsSuperType<5> // true

type Test3 = IsSuperType<number> // false
```

Above `IsSuperType` utility type checks whether `number` is a subtype of `N`. If it is a subtype - than `N` is wrong because it might be much wider that `number`. For instance:

```js
type Test1 = IsSuperType<any> // true
```

So we need to make sure that `number` is not subtype of `N`.
See another example:

```js
type IsLiteralNumber<N extends number> =
    /**
     * If N is a subtype of number
     */
    (N extends number
          /**
           * and number is not subtype of N
           */
        ? (number extends N
            ? false
            /**
             * it is literal type of number: 5, 10, 42 ....
             */
            : true)
        : true)
```

> 2. About because TS is unaware how long is any[] array ....

Here is a type of `Array` from standard lib:

```js
interface Array<T> {
  /**
   * Gets or sets the length of the array. This is a number one higher than the highest index in the array.
   */
  length: number;
}
```

Property `length` byt the default is just a `number`. However, TS is able to infer the length of the literal array `tuple`. That's it.

> 3. Why then conditionals are allowed syntactically in the return type section if they are not supported

Conditional types are supported inside overload signatures because they (overloads) are less strict, in fact, they are bivariant.

Comment: Thank you! I scanned it quickly and it looks like a valid implementation, although it's super complicated for a "simple trick" as to me. I will go into it in detail later today.

Comment: @KarpovKirill I will add more explanation

Comment: @KarpovKirill you will find explanation in comments and tests

Comment: Investigated your solution - it's brilliant, thank you! I have questions. 1. Could you elaborate on that part `N extends number? (number extends N` in particular `number extends N`? 2. About `because TS is unaware how long is any[] array` - it looks like the idea here is that we check if the length is initialized to a literal number at the moment when we use this helper, which allows us to type check some exact array length and empty arrays. Am I thinking in the right direction? 3. Why then conditionals are allowed syntactically in the return type section if they are not supported?

Comment: For the sake of completeness [here is a lightweight solution](https://tsplay.dev/mxBYBw) based on the overloading approach (it does not support high order functions and more general types).

Comment: @KarpovKirill made an update. Hope it is mich clearer now.

Comment: Everything is clear now. Thank you for the comprehensive explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Using a return type of `ListNode | undefined` would be totally sufficient, there is no reason for a conditional type:

```
public static fromArray<T extends number[] | ({ length: 0 } & never[])>(
  array: T,
): undefined | ListNode { /* method implementation */ }
```

What was your intention to use a conditional type expression here in the first place? Since length's is a runtime property and there is no separate "empty array" type (there are good reasons why even purely functional languages still treat empty lists as lists), there is no way to distinguish an empty array from an array on the type level.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I extended the question and added the expected behavior. The idea is to not always have `undefined | ListNode` as the resolved type. I agree that it can be designed in another way as suggested above e.g. with the null object design pattern or to throw an error. But I'd like to solve this puzzle with typings of TS.